# Whats more portable in Perl, sockets or named pipes (fifos)?

Tags: perl, sockets, portability, named-pipes

I'm writing some Perl code.  I want it to run on Windows and Linux/UNIX/OSX.  So far it works on *NIX and uses fifos.

I am considering switching to sockets to avoid the problem that POSIX::mkfifo() doesn't work on Windows, so I need to write some separate code to use Win32::Pipe.

I'm feeling ambivalent about the whole thing.  It seems to me both fixes require about the same amount of work.  Is it a good idea to switch to sockets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Short answer:* IO::Socket::INET works on both Windows and *NIX.

## Named Pipes

- Slightly easier to code up quickly.  You don't need write connect code.
- Slightly faster.  Sockets have the overhead of TCP and setting up the initial connection.
- Works on all platforms.
- Works even when network card doesn't exist.  Some laptops shut down the network card to save power which can prevent even local sockets from working.

## Sockets

- Works on all platforms.  However, some laptops shut down the network card to save power and even local sockets won't work if there is no network interface.
- More portable in Perl.  IO::Socket::INET works on both *NIX and Windows.
- Allows you to have a separate conversation with each client.
- Firewalls are not a problem.  Ports over 1024 should work.

Personally, I've decided to switch to sockets.  In my application it doesn't matter much.  But I think it makes the code a bit simpler, gives me the flexibility to move to > 1 client in the future, and I want to learn IO::Socket anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Answering more generically (ie, it's not perl specific):

Doing this sort of thing in windows vs the rest of the world almost always requires separate code for windows vs everything-else.  Pretty much everything-else has good solutions for things like this, like unix file sockets or fifo's or ...  Then on windows you have to fall back to sockets.

The right thing to do, IMHO, is to use the right solution on windows that *isn't* network sockets because that opens the application up to security issues.  So on everything else "do it correctly" but then on windows, fall back to something like network sockets instead.  *But*, make sure if you take the network-socket route you should at least use local sockets only (ie, bound to 127.0.0.1).

For perl, I'd be tempted to look in CPAN for a class that's already made this generic.  But...  I wouldn't be surprised if nothing exists.

Answer (score 2):

[LWP::socket](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aSocket) works fine in Windows and *NIX. If you opt for sockets over fifos, then you eventually would be able to communicate Windows and *NIX processes. May be you don't need it today, but who knows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  FYI, I see a note in the POD that says "New code should not use this module. The IO::Socket::INET module provide the standard Perl interface to OO Internet sockets. Even LWP is now rewritten to use IO::Socket::INET throughout."

Comment: Thanks for noticing. In fact, i do use IO::Socket::INET on linux, but never tested it on Windows. Thats why i didn't sugggested it (although i think it must work).

Comment: I've used IO::Socket::INET on Windows, and it does work.  I haven't had any issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, later versions of Perl have a working socketpair on Windows.